# Computing an array with a given shape containing powers of x = complex(0, 1)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pow

I am trying to create a 9-lines array (shape = (9,)) containing

**powers of x = complex(0, 1): 1, x, x**2, ..., x**8**.

I do not know if there is someone who knows what is meant by the statement powers of x = complex(0, 1) and how in your opinion this series might be computed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use:

```
out = complex(0,1)**np.arange(9)
```

output:

```
array([ 1.+0.j,  0.+1.j, -1.+0.j, -0.-1.j,  1.+0.j,  0.+1.j, -1.+0.j,
       -0.-1.j,  1.+0.j])
```

If by 9 **lines** you rather mean a shape of (9,1), use instead:

```
out = complex(0,1)**np.arange(9)[:,None]
```

output:

```
array([[ 1.+0.j],
       [ 0.+1.j],
       [-1.+0.j],
       [-0.-1.j],
       [ 1.+0.j],
       [ 0.+1.j],
       [-1.+0.j],
       [-0.-1.j],
       [ 1.+0.j]])
```

explanation:

`np.arange(9)` is creating the array `array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])`, and vectorization of `x**powers` is computing `x**power` for each `power` of `powers`

```
x = complex(0, 1)
# 0 + 1j

powers = np.arange(9)
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

x**powers
# array([ 1.+0.j,   1
#         0.+1.j,   x
#        -1.+0.j,   x**2
#        -0.-1.j,   x**3
#         1.+0.j,
#         0.+1.j,
#        -1.+0.j,
#        -0.-1.j,
#         1.+0.j,   x**8
#         ])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But from the example above, how could I get that the series of complex numbers create is de facto a series of 1, x, x2, ..., x8?

Comment: What means `x`, `x2`, etc.? Can you provide the expected output?

Comment: This is an off topic question but what is IIUC?

Comment: I only know that the series should provide a series of powers of x = complex(0, 1) or  1, x, x2, ..., x8

Comment: hmm is this an assignment? Do you have the full question?

Comment: Why the question is off-topic!!

Comment: @Ishan If I Understand Correctly

Comment: @mały_statystyczny I meant that about my question, not yours. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: It asks to create an array: complex with shape=(9,), powers of x = complex(0, 1): 1, x, x**2, ..., x**8.

Comment: I see, do you mean `x**2, x**3, x**4` etc., the operators got hidden as `**` is formatting for bold

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: then this is what the code is doing

Comment: Great. Could you explain how I can recognise this pattern?